# Why does wrapping a method in another method stop type mismatch in Scala - using underscore in type parameter in pattern match?

Tags: scala, types, covariance, scalac, scala-compiler

In the following block of code (with both scala `2.11` and `2.12`) the method `apply` does not compile, while `applyInlined` does.

```
package blar

trait Bar[T]

class A
class B
class C

trait Exploder[T] {
  // Removing explode and changing Foo so that
  // flatMap takes no param means it will compile
  def explode(product: C): Seq[T]
  val bar: Bar[T]
}

case object Exploder1 extends Exploder[A] {
  def explode(product: C): Seq[A] = ???
  val bar: Bar[A] = ???
}

case object Exploder2 extends Exploder[B] {
  def explode(product: C): Seq[B] = ???
  val bar: Bar[B] = ???
}

object Thing {
  def apply(): Unit = List(Exploder1, Exploder2).foreach {
    case exploder: Exploder[_] =>
      wrapped(exploder)
  }

  def applyInlined(): Unit = List(Exploder1, Exploder2).foreach {
    case exploder: Exploder[_] =>
      flatMap(exploder.explode)(exploder.bar)
  }

  def flatMap[U: Bar](explode: C => TraversableOnce[U]): Unit = ???

  def wrapped[T](exploder: Exploder[T]): Unit =
    flatMap(exploder.explode)(exploder.bar)
}
```

The error message is

```
[error] .../src/main/scala/blar/Bar.scala:34:42: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : blar.Bar[_1]
[error]  required: blar.Bar[Object]
[error] Note: _1 <: Object, but trait Bar is invariant in type T.
[error] You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
[error]       flatMap(exploder.explode)(exploder.bar)
[error]                                          ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed 03-Jan-2019 13:43:45
```

1. My main question is why? Is this a bug?

As you can see `applyInlined` only differs in that it has inlined the body of the `wrapped` method.  This means that somehow the extra wrapping of some code in a method has "tricked" the compiler into working.

2. The other question is can you think of a design/hack that would avoid this kind of thing *without* making `Blar` covariant?  How can I make the inlined version compile? Can I do it with an `asInstanceOf`
3. What is scala inferring the type to be in order to call `wrapped` without an explicit type param?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Because of `[U: Bar]`, `flatMap` expects a second, implicit argument.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Ah yes, of course - my bad.

Answer (score 3):

1. I don't know. Experimental evidence shows that it has something to do with the presence / absence of the explicit `[Exploder[_]]` type annotation on `List`. Without `List[Exploder[_]]`, the inferred type of the list becomes

   ```
   List[Product with Serializable with Exploder[_ >: B with A <: Object]]
   ```

   and for whatever reason, it somehow messes up the subsequent pattern matching. The `B with A` lower bound looks a little suspicious to me, but I can't explain why it would interfere with the pattern matching.
2. No, fortunately, no `asInstanecOf`s are required. Both of the following variants work fine:

   ```
   def applyInlined: Unit = List[Exploder[_]](Exploder1, Exploder2).foreach {
     case exploder: Exploder[t] => {
       flatMap(exploder.explode)(exploder.bar)
     }
   }
   ```

   same with a separately declared implicit variable (note that now you have some type `t` to refer to):

   ```
   def applyInlined2: Unit = List[Exploder[_]](Exploder1, Exploder2).foreach {
     case exploder: Exploder[t] => {
       implicit val bar: Bar[t] = exploder.bar
       flatMap(exploder.explode)
     }
   }
   ```

   See [Type parameter inference in patterns](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/08-pattern-matching.html#type-parameter-inference-in-patterns) for more about the `[t]`-part.
3. I assume it's some synthetic dummy type `_1`.

Comment: Thanks Andrey, especially for answer 2, now I can inline that useless method.  Would be interesting to understand "for whatever reason, it somehow messes up the subsequent pattern matching".